# Encoding on NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ios, encoding, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I need to load data from a REST service, but the result is always (null) when I have any accentuation. I know this is an encoding problem but NSUrlConnection gives me no solution. The best result I got is to have all my text with strange codes in the place of the accentuated characters.

I already tried to use NSUrl like the following code and it works, but I need to set two headers for this connection.

```
NSURL *nsurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:nsurl encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
```

Well I could have two solutions for this taks, adding headers do NSUrl connection or manage to make the encoding to work in NSURLConnection.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add header fields for your request in an [NSMutableURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableURLRequest) instance with `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`

Comment: How do you set the encoding? And: What encoding exactly you want to set?

Comment: Testing with NSURL the NSUTF8StringEncoding works, but it doesn't accept headers.

Comment: You may test the encoding for NsURLConnection with these files:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cardcell/web.xml
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cardcell/web2.xml

They have this xml node with an accentuation: <a>joão</a>.
One uses UTF-8 and another ISO-8859-1.